# How to start printing a StringListProperty() from index [1]?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, list

I have a model

```
class Category(db.Model):
   merchandise = db.StringListProperty()
   content = db.StringListProperty()         
   topics = db.StringListProperty()
```

For instance, `merchandise` list is `["merchandise","tshirt","book","poster"]`

I print the list like this

```
elif merchandise_type == "merchandise":
    query = Category.all()
    e = query.get()

    self.response.out.write("""<ul>""")
    for i in range(len(e.merchandise)):
        self.response.out.write("""<li><a href="/tag?tag=%s">%s</a></li>""" 
        % (e.merchandise[i], e.merchandise[i]))
    self.response.out.write("""</ul>""")
```

but I don't want to print `"merchandise"`.

How do I start from `e.merchandise[1]` instead of `e.merchandise[0]`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not `for merchandise_item in e.merchandise: ...`? As a rule of thumb, if you're using `range(len(...))` and use anything except the indices themselves, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @delnan: thanks! I changed the lines accordingly. I did not know that I could loop without stating the range. Where do I look for further info?

Comment: @Zeyel: A Python tutorial. Seriously. If you don't know that `for` always works on iterables and `range` is just one particular iterable, you don't know the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in range(1, len(e.merchandise)):` changing the first argument of `range()` will start the loop from 1 instead of 0

Edit: changed `len()` to `range()`, silly mistake

Comment: Great, thanks! By the way, I think you meant "changing the first argument of `range()` and not `len()`."

Answer (score 3):

```
for merch in e.merchandise[1:]:
    self.response.out.write('<li><a href="/tag?tag=%s">%s<a/></li>' % (merch, merch))
```

Question, of course, is why do you have such first element in your list in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I realized this is not a good idea because I changed the sort order and "merchandise" is no longer the first item. I put "merchandise" as the first in the list to use as the category name in the directory page. I will ask another question about how to get the property name from the datastore.